# Word and noun similarity Python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, similarity, cpu-word

I have a simple problem in Python using NLTK. I want to check similarities between words. After some research, I'm trying to use `wordnet.synsets()`. But I don't understang some results:

```
syns1 = wordnet.synsets('location')
syns2 = wordnet.synsets('located')

for s1, s2 in product(syns1, syns2):
    print("%s -- %s :" % (s1, s2))
    print(s1.wup_similarity(s2)

Synset('location.n.01') -- Synset('locate.v.01') :
None
Synset('location.n.01') -- Synset('situate.v.01') :
None
Synset('location.n.01') -- Synset('locate.v.03') :
None
Synset('location.n.01') -- Synset('settle.v.04') :
None
Synset('location.n.01') -- Synset('located.s.01') :
None
Synset('placement.n.03') -- Synset('locate.v.01') :
None
Synset('placement.n.03') -- Synset('situate.v.01') :
None
Synset('placement.n.03') -- Synset('locate.v.03') :
None
Synset('placement.n.03') -- Synset('settle.v.04') :
None
Synset('placement.n.03') -- Synset('located.s.01') :
None
Synset('localization.n.01') -- Synset('locate.v.01') :
None
Synset('localization.n.01') -- Synset('situate.v.01') :
None
Synset('localization.n.01') -- Synset('locate.v.03') :
None
Synset('localization.n.01') -- Synset('settle.v.04') :
None
Synset('localization.n.01') -- Synset('located.s.01') :
None
Synset('location.n.04') -- Synset('locate.v.01') :
None
Synset('location.n.04') -- Synset('situate.v.01') :
None
Synset('location.n.04') -- Synset('locate.v.03') :
None
Synset('location.n.04') -- Synset('settle.v.04') :
None
Synset('location.n.04') -- Synset('located.s.01') :
None
```

Can someone explain me why this happens and how to have a good result for word similarity ? I know one is a noun and the other is a verb/adj but hey common it's 99% the same !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different types of similarities often looked at,
the issue you seem to have is because it is a syntactic difference as well.
If you want to have only a character level match and a similarity based on it, then you can try :

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
word1 = "location"
word2 = "located"
similarity = fuzz.ratio(word1,word2)
print(similarity)
```

However if you do want to check with wordnet and relate to more than a character match. I would suggest you to first lemmatize your word and then run it through the check.

```
from pattern.en import lemma
word1 = "located"
lemma_word1 = lemma(word1)
```

Comment: Thank you, both are working, but I'll use the second method because nltk provides stemmatization and lemmatization, and I would like to only use one library.